# Mocking CloudBlockBlob and CloudBlobStream and reading from it

Tags: c#, moq, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to mock CloudBlobStream and read what is written to it. So far I have this: I think I need to use a call back so when stuff is written to it, it is also written to my memory stream so I can read from it?

```
        var exportFile = new Mock<CloudBlockBlob>(new Uri("http://example.com/container"));
        _exportStorageProvider.Setup(a => a.CreateFileAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(exportFile.Object);
        var stream = new Mock<CloudBlobStream>();
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        exportFile.Setup(a => a.OpenWriteAsync())
            .Callback(() => { return memoryStream; } )
            .ReturnsAsync(stream.Object);
```

The code that is being executed is as follows:

```
            var exportFile = await _exportStorageProvider.CreateFileAsync(exportFileName);
            using (var exportStream = await exportFile.OpenWriteAsync())
            {
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Async = true };
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(exportStream, settings))
```

I am using Moq and C#

I want to test that the correct content is written by the XMLWriter to the exportStream. exportStream is mocked, but XMLWriter is not. I've read elsewhere there are problems with mocking bits of the .net framework like XmlWriter. It seems to me that I need to know what method XmlWriter.Create calls on exportStream when it is passed in as a parameter so I can return an appropriate stub?

Comment: Is it really necessary though? I usually get around things like this by abstracting away the third-party components, otherwise you often just end up testing your Nuget packages.

Comment: I fail to see how I am testing NuGet packages by ensuring the business logic in the system is working correctly by writing the correct content to the blob.

Comment: Is it _worth_ testing that bit tho? Could you create a super thin wrapper around the block blob and just accept that that won’t be tested? I’m terms of code coverage what would you be missing out?

Comment: I would be missing out on all the XML that I am writing to the blob which is important for my process. My understanding is blockblob was written with virtual methods rather than against an interface to aid testing, so I was hoping there was some way of doing what I set out to

Comment: Also XmlWriter.Create must be calling a method on exportStream to return XmlWriter writer, hence why I think this is possible

Comment: What's generating the XML that's being written to the CloudBlob? Is it possible to test that directly. When I've done this in the past I've had a thin (as thin as possible) class that manages the orchestration of the process and tested the other components. That way you minimise the un-covered code, but you're testing the important bits. i.e. the XML generation, and you can test the business logic calls into `IFooWriterManager.WriteData(CloudBlockBlob, XmlDataFoo)` for which you provide a mock.